# android fragment- How to save states of views in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-tab-host

I use Tabhost have: Fragment A, Fragment B, Fragment C
I want to save states of views in a fragment when switch(not construct view)
I use addToBackStack but not activity
Help me

Comment: Elaborate your question, nothing is clear in this.

Comment: Use the same instance of fragment when using fragment transaction.. meaning not always calling new BlahblahFragment. but the variable of the fragment instead